# In Xcode, Locale.current.Identifier when running tests uses a different format than the format for running the app

Tags: xcode, testing, localization, xctest

In a test plan in Xcode, I set up the region to be Canada and the language to be fr-CA. The value of `Locale.current.identifier`, in either the main target or the test target, is `fr-CA_CA`.

However, if I run the app with the device set to region Canada and language fr-CA, `Locale.current.identifier` returns `fr-CA`

Why does it behave differently?

The same thing happens if you choose France and language fr-CA.  You end up with "fr-CA_FR" in tests and "fr-FR" when running the app.

This format used by tests doesn't seem to be documented and certainly seems to break Apple's own list found in `Locale.availableIdentifiers`